# Criar nova row com input na tabela quando apertar enter

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Estou criando uma tabela usando AngularJS e Bootstrap. Gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar uma nova linha ao chegar no final e apertar a tecla enter?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o importante é pegar o codigo do botão enter e depois criar a nova linha dentro do array

```
$scope.addline = function ($event) {
    debugger

    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var algo = {};
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.etc.Fields.length; i++) {

            algo["seu array"] = ""

        }

        $scope.myArrayData.push(algo);

    }
}
```

Comment: as duas teclas enter do teclado tem o mesmo id ne?